# how to get values of the some keys in Array of Dictionary in Dart Flutter?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dictionary, dart, iterable

I have an Array of the Dictionary which the Dictionary contains many key values , I just want one keys values be in an array I do not want to loop Throw that with for loop I want some mapping but I do not know why it will sho0w me Error

So here is an Example

```
static final myDictionary = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Alex",
  "field_of_work": "HR",
  "description": ""
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Jack",
  "field_of_work": "CEO",
  "description": ""
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Eric",
  "field_of_work": "Worker",
  "description": ""
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Sam",
  "field_of_work": "Computer",
  "description": ""
},
{"id": 5, "name": "Michael", "field_of_work": "Others", "description": ""}
];
```

and I want my list be some thing like this

```
['Alex','Jack','Eric','Sam','Michael']
```

so here is the Code Which I wrote but Does not work (actually doe not compile)

```
myDictionary.asMap().values['name'].toList()
```

and here is the Error

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<Map<String, Object>>'.
```

Try defining the operator '[]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it like this

```
 final List<String> namesList = myDictionary.map((e) => e["name"].toString()).toList();
```

Comment: Please, don't write `List` as the type. You are removing the generic type of the result from `toList` which makes it `List<dynamic>`. Use instead `List<String>`, `var` or `final`.

Comment: now it's worked but right now I need to check the same array and return index of the item which is in that array

Comment: I didn't understand you , can you explain more

Comment: I did it  it was .indexOf() to get the index of the element which is in this array of String